# expo publish from windows to apple store

Tags: ios, visual-studio-code, expo, publish

I have an app publish in both Apple Store and Google Play, but I want to publish little updates without going through the stores.

I'm on windows using VSCode with expo react native and I'm afraid of having problems with apple store.

Is there's any problem of using `expo publish` from a VSCode on **Windows** to OAT update my iOS app? And if there's a problem, how can I `expo publish` only for Android, I've already searched in a lot of places, but the solutions seems too complex, even in the expo site itself.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience using `expo publish` does not give me errors, everything was perfect, and my new changes were sent through the over-the-air updates that expo has.